# Arquivo .htaccess configurações

Tags: htaccess

Olá nobres amigos sou um iniciante aqui no Stack Overflow e iniciante em programação  Vôvo de 04 netos 54 anos. 
Qual configuração fazer no .htaccess para proteção de diretórios, pastas, arquivos e DB de acessos via navegador. Grato.

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow, para começar faça um [tour] leia atentamente cada passo, e depois olhe [ask], veja como fazer uma pergunta corretamente, simples e objetiva.

Comment: Você também pode usar o .htpasswd para por senhas nos diretórios.

Answer (score 0):

A opção que você procura é essa:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Pode por direto nos `.htaccess` (se estiver habilitado esse override no `Apache`).

Exemplo de configuração com `Directory`, em vez de `.htaccess`:

```
<Directory /caminho> 
    Options -Indexes 
</Directory>
```

Documentação (en):

> https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/sections.html#file-and-web

Link Útil:

> [20 dicas e truques extremamente úteis do .htaccess](https://codigofonte.uol.com.br/artigos/confira-20-dicas-e-truques-extremamente-uteis-do-htaccess)

Comment: Muito obrigado Sr. Darlei Fernando Zillmer...Consegui realizar as devidas alterações.